# Starting, Stopping, and Continuing the Google App Engine BulkLoader

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bulkloader

I have quite of bit of data that I will be uploading into Google App Engine. I want to use the bulkloader to help get it in there. However, I have so much data that I generally use up my CPU quota before it's done. Also, any other problem such a bad internet connection or random computer issue can stop the process.

Is there any way to continue a bulkload from where you left off? Or to only bulkload data that has not been written to the datastore?

I couldn't find anything in the docs, so I assume any answer will include digging into the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is in the docs:

> If the transfer is interrupted, you
>   can resume the transfer from where it
>   left off using the --db_filename=...
>   argument. The value is the name of the
>   progress file created by the tool,
>   which is either a name you provided
>   with the --db_filename argument when
>   you started the transfer, or a default
>   name that includes a timestamp. This
>   assumes you have sqlite3 installed,
>   and did not disable the progress file
>   with --db_filename=skip.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html

(I've used it some time ago, so I had a feeling it should be there)